# if I have an iphone's IP address is there anyway I can communicate with it?

Tags: iphone, client-server, ip-address

are there any services running by default on an iphone that would let another ip address communicate with it if the iphone's ip is known?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to open communications to an iPhone without the users permission?

Comment: I guess but then isn't that what text messaging is? I want to find out if there are other methods of communication with iphones other than normal phone use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, technically, you can. There are a couple of issues though:

1. Mobile IP addresses usually change
2. When the phone is in sleep mode, its network interface is probably not reachable.

So I don't think you can rely on that for initiating a communication with the phone.

Comment: well, you have a couple. it depends on what mobile devices you are targeting.

Comment: @rutherford: for the iPhone, use Push Notifications to remotely start a conversation with your phone.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many options out of the box on a non jail-broken phone.  However, you can write your own client application that runs on the phone.  It accepts or initiates the remote connection.

And in that case, the protocol is entirely up to you.

If you jailbreak your phone, you can install the OpenSSH package and have SSH and SFTP access to your phone.

Comment: if the phone is already jail broken is there any comms services available without installing my own special client?

Comment: SSH would be the big one that is available to install from Cydia.  That would give you both SSH and SFTP so you could upload files.  Note that you *must* change the default root password if you install SSH.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to do with your app, but you can consider create a thread detached from the main one (using gcd) and use it to send/receive informations from a server using JSON objects for example. Sure you can use sockets and write a client or something like that.
I suggested a new thread because you can put it running forever (on a enterprise app, I don't know if Apple will approve a thread running on an App for AppStore).
I had to develop an app with a consistent client/server relationship and it was the way I got it working.

Comment: I want to use an existing service on the iphone not create my own